# Definition of $\Delta$-complex: restriction to interior is homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

From Hatcher's *Algebraic Topology*, the definition of a $\Delta$-complex is:

[image]

Then, a page or so later, he writes:

[image]

Regarding the sentence "Condition (iii) then implies...", I don't understand why he mentions Hausdorfness. The restriction is a bijection, and then by (iii) an open mapping, so Hausdorffness is unnecessary, right? (Open bijective continuous function is a homeomorphism.)

I don't even see how Hausdorffness would help...$\overset{\circ}{\Delta}{}^n$ is not compact. How is Hausdorffness relevant?

Comment: Condition (iii) says that $\sigma_\alpha$ is continuous, not necessarily open.

Comment: @WilliamStagner It is stronger than continuity. And along with the fact that the restriction of $\sigma_\alpha$ is a bijection (and each point is in the interior of a unique simplex) it implies openness (unless I am mistaken).

Comment: If $\sigma_\alpha : \Delta^n \to X$ were an open map then, since $\Delta^n$ is always an open subset of $\Delta^n$, it would follow that $\sigma_\alpha(\Delta^n)$ is always an open subset of $X$. But quite the opposite is true, very rarely is $\sigma_\alpha(\Delta^n)$ open in $X$.

Comment: Condition (3) does not imply that the maps are open, but it does imply that the restriction to $\overset{\circ}{\Delta}{}^n$ and corestriction to the image is an open map. It actually literally says that each $\sigma_\alpha$ is a quotient map onto its image. Maybe the key point is that a bijective quotient map is a homeomorphism.